# Manually add entries to the bibliography without writing them to the .bib file

Tags: bibtex

I use a joint `.bib` file with some co-authors. In addition I want to add some entries to the bibliography without writing them into the `.bib` file. How is that possible?

Comment: you can reference multiple bib files so the easiest thing is just to put your extra entries into an extra bib file.

Comment: OK, I see that - though it's not actually an answer to my question - this might be the best solution. I'd say either @David Carlisle turns his comment into an answer so that I can accept it or we decide the question was not a good one and delete it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reference multiple `.bib` files so the easiest thing is just to put your extra entries into an extra `.bib` file.

If you do not want to use BibTeX on your additional entries then you need to give a lot more context. Is the BibTeX generated list sorted by alphabetical order or order of appearance or anything else, and if so do these additional entries have to be slotted into the correct places, or can they be added at the start or the end or...